# Why not able to get the page and search form with login details (selenium, Beautifulsoup)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape this  [this](https://www.couriermail.com.au/) for some of my natural language processing work. I have a subscription to the website but still, I am not able to get the result. I got the error that unable to locate the element.
The link to login page is [login](https://login.newscorpaustralia.com/login?state=hKFo2SBmOXc1TjRJNDlBX3hObkZPN1NsRWgzcktONTlPVnJMS6FupWxvZ2luo3RpZNkgUi1ZRmV2Z2dwcWJmZUpqdWtZdk5CUUllX0h3YngwanSjY2lk2SAwdjlpN0tvVzZNQkxTZmUwMzZZU1FUNzl6QThaYXo0WQ&client=0v9i7KoW6MBLSfe036YSQT79zA8Zaz4Y&protocol=oauth2&response_type=token%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&audience=newscorpaustralia&site=couriermail&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.couriermail.com.au%2Fremote%2Fidentity%2Fauth%2Flatest%2Flogin%2Fcallback.html%3FredirectUri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.couriermail.com.au%252Fsearch-results%253Fq%253Djason%252520huny&prevent_sign_up=true&nonce=7j4grLXRD39EVhGsxcagsO5c-PtAY4Md&auth0Client=eyJuYW1lIjoiYXV0aDAuanMiLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiOS4xOS4wIn0%3D)

This is the code that I tried in python with selenium.

```
                options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
                options.add_argument('--incognito')
                options.add_argument('--headless')
                options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
                options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
                options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
                options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
                options.add_argument("disable-infobars")

                driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=options)
                driver.get('https://login.newscorpaustralia.com/login?state=hKFo2SBmOXc1TjRJNDlBX3hObkZPN1NsRWgzcktONTlPVnJMS6FupWxvZ2luo3RpZNkgUi1ZRmV2Z2dwcWJmZUpqdWtZdk5CUUllX0h3YngwanSjY2lk2SAwdjlpN0tvVzZNQkxTZmUwMzZZU1FUNzl6QThaYXo0WQ&client=0v9i7KoW6MBLSfe036YSQT79zA8Zaz4Y&protocol=oauth2&response_type=token%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&audience=newscorpaustralia&site=couriermail&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.couriermail.com.au%2Fremote%2Fidentity%2Fauth%2Flatest%2Flogin%2Fcallback.html%3FredirectUri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.couriermail.com.au%252Fsearch-results%253Fq%253Djason%252520huny&prevent_sign_up=true&nonce=7j4grLXRD39EVhGsxcagsO5c-PtAY4Md&auth0Client=eyJuYW1lIjoiYXV0aDAuanMiLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiOS4xOS4wIn0%3D')
                time.sleep(10)
                
                elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME,value='navigation_search')
                username = driver.find_element(by=By.ID,value='1-email')
                password = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME,value='password')
                login = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME,value='submit')
                username.send_keys("myid");
                password.send_keys("password");
                login.click();
                time.sleep(20)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
               
                search = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='form.navigation_search')
                search.click();
                search.send_keys("jason hunt");

                print(driver.page_source)
```

Below is the error that I am getting. I want to grab the search icon and send the keys there but I am not getting the search form after login.
Below is the text based HTML of the element.
I tried printing the page source and I was not able to locate the html element there too.

[image: HTML]

[image: error]

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML of the element.

Comment: @mashal You could just manually enter the search parameter in as a URL query. For example, rather than sending the keys 'example' to the search bar, you could just driver.get to `https://www.couriermail.com.au/search-results?q=example`

Comment: @Thorium I tried that but I was blocked

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I added the image

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer, but since you can't add formatting to comments and this has the same desired effect:

```
driver.get("https://www.couriermail.com.au/search-results");

WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "search_box_input"))
searchBox = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "search_box_input")
searchBox.send_keys("test");
```

Comment: Im getting the timeout error. ad its probably beause of this <html><head></head><body>       <h2>Potential automated action detected!</h2><h2>

Comment: Are you using `driver.get("https://www.couriermail.com.au/")`, or are you using `driver.get("https://www.couriermail.com.au/search-results")` like I showed in my example?

Comment: I used    driver.get("https://www.couriermail.com.au/search-results");

Comment: Ah, I just saw your edit. If there's automation detection, I'm not sure I can help you. If you're using headless mode, maybe try to run it in normal mode.

Comment: so your suggestion to not use headless mode is working but I have a question how can I stop browser to not load its really annoying